# Send FCM messages from server side to android device

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

With the new update, FCM is now going to be used.

I tried the sample app from git and it's working all fine. I can send notifications from the console.

But I want to send the notification from the server after a certain event is triggered. I followed the same approach like in GCM but it's not working.

```
05-20 20:40:58.941 30132-30919/com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-1-thread-1
                                                                                    Process: com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm, PID: 30132
                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage$Notification.getBody()' on a null object reference
                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived(MyFirebaseMessagingService.java:53)
                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzo(Unknown Source)
                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzn(Unknown Source)
                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzm(Unknown Source)
                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb$2.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-20 20:40:59.118 30132-30279/com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb9e83390
```

Am following this [PHP Script](https://gist.github.com/prime31/5675017) to send the notification. 
If I try to execute the script, I get the following result.

```
{"multicast_id":4679427854122301046,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1463757518309261%31bd1c96f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

NOTE : I went through their [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref#notification-payload-support) and modified the code is gist to have only body and title. Even then it's not working.

Comment: Could you add the message you are sending? It seems like your message does not contain a body, which could be the reason for the null pointer.

Comment: Ismael is right. Hereby my answer:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358462/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called-when-app-in-background/37471326#37471326](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358462/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called-when-app-in-background/37471326#37471326)

Answer (score 16):

You can use this complete code

```
<?php

function sendFCM($mess,$id) {
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$fields = array (
        'to' => $id,
        'notification' => array (
                "body" => $mess,
                "title" => "Title",
                "icon" => "myicon"
        )
);
$fields = json_encode ( $fields );
$headers = array (
        'Authorization: key=' . "AIzaSyA9vpL9OuX6moOYw-4n3YTSXpoSGQVGnyM",
        'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );

$result = curl_exec ( $ch );
curl_close ( $ch );
}

?>
```

Pass message and token id as a parameter to the `sendFCM($mess,$id)` call.

Answer (score 9):

I tried this and worked:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
$header=array('Content-Type: application/json',
"Authorization: key=GoGdfsflknEFñslknaglksjfnklj");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{ \"notification\": {    \"title\": \"Test desde curl\",    \"text\": \"Otra prueba\"  },    \"to\" : \"SGferg-qWEFWbI:dflñkndfakllvakrgalkgjdgjslfkgjdglksdjflksjglkjlkñerhTHDFSHFZDHzdfakjsdhskjhgkjashfdasjdkf\"}");

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

This is the result:

```
{"multicast_id":4913280949692448120,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1473389987003950%ab9a0bb6ab9a0bb6"}]}
```

Comment: i think the above script is only for the one user if i want to send the PUSH Message to many...

Comment: How can i store this result in variable ?

Answer (score 3):

In order to receive the notification using        ***remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()***, you have to use the predefined set of key option for notification.

In this case, **"notification"** is the key word.

The JSON response has to be formatted like this.

```
   {
      "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
      "notification" : {
          "body" : "great match!",
          "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
          "icon" : "myicon"
      }
   }
```

You can also send notification and data payload in the same JSON response

```
 {
    "to" : "APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...",
    "notification" : {
        "body" : "great match!",
        "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
        "icon" : "myicon"
    },
    "data" : {
        "Nick" : "Mario",
        "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
 }
```

see this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#messages-with-both-notification-and-data-payloads

Answer (score 2):

From the php gist you are sending a data only message. Your receiver is expecting a notification message so when you get the notification from the remote message it will be null, resulting in a NPE when you call getBody.

Send a notification message and it should work as expected. See notification message requirements here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support

Comment: Yeah. When i try to get the data by `remoteMessage.getData().get("body");` am getting the text. Any idea how to create a notification there? The doc specifies the fields required but how do I create a `notification` there?

Comment: The data object and notification object are siblings, so you can use the notification fields from the docs to create a notification object at the same level that you had the data object.

Comment: I'll try that out.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue and after spending some time trying to find out the cause , my observation was --

Since the "notification" field is JSON representation of the [RemoteMessage.Notification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage.Notification#public-method-summary%20class) . 
If you set any of the predefined fields of the Notification class in the "notification" field , on client side the JSON is successfully parsed and you have a non-null value for **`RemoteMessage.getNotification()`** on which you can call the **`getBody()`** / **`getTopic()`** / **`getIcon()`**.

But if you don't set any field of the Notification class in the "notification" json field, the parsing to class fails and you will have a null value for **`RemoteMessage.getNotification()`**

So, any of the following three JSONs is a valid POST body for pushing a **`RemoteMessage.Notification`** ( in addition to the two examples shared by Andrea in earlier answer ) , i.e. these three won't cause the above NPE

```
    {
      "to" : "<<FIREBASE_INSTANCE_ID>>",
      "notification" : {
          "body" : "Notification Message Body"
      }
    }

    {
      "to" : "<<FIREBASE_INSTANCE_ID>>",
      "notification" : {
          "title" : "Notification Title"
      }
    }

    {
      "to" : "<<FIREBASE_INSTANCE_ID>>",
      "notification" : {
          "icon" : "Notification icon"
      }
    }
```

And none of the following three are valid for pushing a RemoteMessage.Notification -

1. Doesn't have the "notification" field

   ```
   {
     "to" : "<<FIREBASE_INSTANCE_ID>>"
   }
   ```
2. "notification" field is an empty json

   ```
   {
     "to" : "<<FIREBASE_INSTANCE_ID>>",
     "notification" : {
     }
   }
   ```
3. "notification" field has some key value pairs , but none of the fields defined in RemoteMessage.Notification class

   ```
   {
       "to" : "<<FIREBASE_INSTANCE_ID>>",
       "notification" : {
           "messageText" : "Notification Message Text",
           "messageBody" : "Notification Message Body"
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```html
function send_fcm($tokens,$message)
          {

     $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
     $priority="high";
   
 
     $fields = array(
          'registration_ids' =>$tokens,         
           'data' =>$message
            
         );

  
     $headers = array(
          'Authorization:key=your key',
          'Content-Type: application/json'
          );

     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
   echo  json_encode($fields);
     $result = curl_exec($ch);           
     curl_error($ch);
     if ($result === FALSE)
      {
         die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
         }
                  curl_close($ch);
                  return $result;
             }
```

store device ids in token variable in an array format

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code this will give push notication for Android from php server side and you can get the device token from android you need pass dynamically to get push notication for more android device.

```
<?php
 function sendmessage_android($devicetoken,$message){ 
        $api_key     =   'AIzaSyCtDch9K3ZqGF_SSLYCz4JjMS4-fkJuW';//get the api key from FCM backend
        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
        $fields = array('registration_ids'  => array($devicetoken));//get the device token from Android 
        $headers = array( 'Authorization: key=' . $api_key,'Content-Type: application/json');
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields) );
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if(curl_errno($ch)){
            return 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        $cur_message=json_decode($result);
        if($cur_message->success==1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
}
?>
```