# FCM receive message Issue

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm integrating FCM to my project. But I'm getting below error in Log while notification received. (Error text color is blue)

```
W/FirebaseMessaging: Received message with unknown type: text
```

My code is like this:

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d("Notification", "Success");
        sendNotification(remoteMessage);
}
```

In this code, the first line is not executing and it is not debugging also.

Comment: did you tried sending notification from console

Comment: Yess... I tried from console. It received succssfully and I parse the notification also.. it working correctly but when I send notification from PHP side at that time this issue will occurs.

Comment: Refer this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37350268/send-fcm-messages-from-server-side-to-android-device

Comment: Looks like the issue is on the sending side, so if Shrenik's suggestion does not help, you should add your sending code to the question.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I got the solution and I posted it below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I got the solution

In php side I'm sending

```
"message_type":"text"
```

That's why I got above error.

As "**message_type**" keyword is predefined by FCM so it is conflicting. So change that keyword in PHP code.

Comment: ok but how did you fix it? did you remove this line from your code or replaced it by something else?

Comment: "message_type" keyword is predefined by FCM so it is conflicting. So I change that keyword in PHP code.

Comment: Yes, after I post my comment I googled a bit figured that out. Here is the link for future reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server : "In addition to regular FCM messages, control messages are sent, indicated by the message_type field in the JSON object. The value can be either 'ack' or 'nack', or 'control' (see formats below). Any FCM message with an unknown message_type can be ignored by your server."