# XMPP server in java does not receive all messages from GCM server

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging, xmpp, smack

I've implemented XMPP server using Smack library, my server gets messages from Google Cloud Messaging server (now it is Firebase), but the problem is when I send  one by one message from android to gcm server, my XMPP server receives only first message and the second is intercepted, (I can see only notification that there was a message

```
<message id="gQaM0-6"><gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">{"message_type":"ack","message_id":"0","to":"eVtypIWW7Q8:APA91bH5oU0AC3zyuCAWVYkMzoGQeIiGe71c2BL4lE5uFHRfB3iPXtD-qIJDmJZ3ySsPDi0VhkKl0Cz3XZG7rWa1Ca7pX9yQqzWSMXBiGK4SEO4Q-Owfr45E_VBJMrXqsSziuJhek"}</gcm></message>
```

but I don't have data in this
 and first message I get in method void processPacket(Packet packet)
here is the full code of XMPP server:

```
public class XMPPServer implements PacketListener {

    private static XMPPServer sInstance = null;
    private XMPPConnection connection;
    private ConnectionConfiguration config;
    private String mApiKey = null;
    private String mProjectId = null;
    private boolean mDebuggable = false;
    private String fcmServerUsername = null;

    public static XMPPServer getInstance() {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("You have to prepare the client first");
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    public static XMPPServer prepareClient(String projectId, String apiKey, boolean debuggable) {
        synchronized (XMPPServer.class) {
            if (sInstance == null) {
                sInstance = new XMPPServer(projectId, apiKey, debuggable);
            }
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    private XMPPServer(String projectId, String apiKey, boolean debuggable) {
        this();
        mApiKey = apiKey;
        mProjectId = projectId;
        mDebuggable = debuggable;
        fcmServerUsername = mProjectId + "@" + Util.FCM_SERVER_CONNECTION;
    }

    private XMPPServer() {
        // Add GcmPacketExtension
        ProviderManager.getInstance().addExtensionProvider(Util.FCM_ELEMENT_NAME, Util.FCM_NAMESPACE,
                new PacketExtensionProvider() {

                    @Override
                    public PacketExtension parseExtension(XmlPullParser parser) throws Exception {
                        String json = parser.nextText();
                        GcmPacketExtension packet = new GcmPacketExtension(json);
                        return packet;
                    }
                });
    }

    /**
     * Connects to FCM Cloud Connection Server using the supplied credentials
     */
    public void connect() throws XMPPException {
        config = new ConnectionConfiguration(Util.FCM_SERVER, Util.FCM_PORT);
        config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.enabled);
        config.setReconnectionAllowed(true);
        config.setSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault());
        // Launch a window with info about packets sent and received
        config.setDebuggerEnabled(mDebuggable);

        connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
        connection.connect();

        connection.addConnectionListener(new ConnectionListener() {
                //a few overrided methods
        });
        // Handle incoming packets (the class implements the PacketListener)
        connection.addPacketListener(this, new PacketTypeFilter(Message.class));

        // Second message without data I get in this method (1)
        connection.addPacketWriterInterceptor(new PacketInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void interceptPacket(Packet packet) {
                System.out.println("INTERCEPT PACKAGE: " + packet.toXML());
            }
        }, new PacketTypeFilter(Message.class));
        connection.login(fcmServerUsername, mApiKey);
    }
    /**
     * Normal message with my data I get in this method (2)
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
        Message incomingMessage = (Message) packet;
        GcmPacketExtension gcmPacket = (GcmPacketExtension) incomingMessage.getExtension(Util.FCM_NAMESPACE);
        String json = gcmPacket.getJson();
        System.out.println("Message : " + json);
     }
```

There is almost the whole code, the most important part I marked with (1) and (2), (use search to find quickly)
Why can I receive only first message with my data ? 
And why does the second message go to PacketInterceptor (mark (1) ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using [Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref), check if your app server is connected to the following endpoints:

```
// Production
fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com:5235

// Testing
fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com:5236
```

In addition to that, you may want to also check [Downstream messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#format) wherein it was mentioned that once the XMPP connection is established, CCS and your server use normal XMPP `<message>` stanzas to send JSON-encoded messages back and forth. The body of the `<message>` must be:

```
<gcm xmlns:google:mobile:data>
    JSON payload
</gcm>
```

Also, note of the exceptions in JSON payload for regular FCM messages. Visit the given links for more information.

These related SO posts might also help:

- [FCM receive message Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39845040/fcm-receive-message-issue)
- [Send FCM messages from server side to android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37350268/send-fcm-messages-from-server-side-to-android-device)

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer! I use FCM_PORT = 5236, I will try 5235, maybe this will change situation