# Showing notification using phpmyadmin

Tags: php, android, firebase, phpmyadmin, notifications

I have made forum app (android) it uses web services to send/retrieve data from database (phpmyadmin). Now when a new question is added then everyone using the app should get a headsup notification that there is a new question. After searching every where I found that FCM should be used but I'm not getting how to use Firebase with my existing database because I want all the data to be stored in my database and also show notification.

Comment: Here is a library you can use https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php

Answer (score 1):

You can pick what Firebase features you want to use. So if you use Firebase Cloud Messaging, you don't have to use the Firebase Database. You can just stick to your own database and call out to FCM from your PHP code.

Some examples of calling FCM:

- [How can I send a Firebase Cloud Messaging notification without use the Firebase Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371990/how-can-i-send-a-firebase-cloud-messaging-notification-without-use-the-firebase)
- [Send FCM messages from server side to android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37350268/send-fcm-messages-from-server-side-to-android-device)
- [many of the results in this list](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+call+FCM+from+PHP)