# how to send notification to single device firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I developing shopping app and I want when the client buy a product send notification to market this owner the product and when the market agree send notification to the client who buy the product but all videos on the internet explain how to send notification to all users app.

Comment: Would you like to send notifications via API or send it directly using consle firebase?

Comment: if I can send notification from my API on server and receive it on my app (android - IOS) its OK to save my time OR send directly from the app, but I prefer from server.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40256179/5251783