# Migrate from GCM to FCM

Tags: java, php, android

Recently I`ve migrated from GCM to FCM and past few days I'm struggling to make it work.

Android Apps are receiving notifications from google firebase console but they don't from php server.

This is my PHP server side code:

```
<?php



define("GOOGLE_API_KEY", Setting::get('browser_key') ? Setting::get('browser_key') : "");


class GCM {

function __construct() {

}


public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {

    Log::info("GOOGLE_API_KEY".GOOGLE_API_KEY);

    include_once 'const.php';
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data' => $message,
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    Log::info('***** PUSH MESSAGE ******'.print_r(json_encode($fields),true));

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    Log::info(print_r($result,true));

    if ($result === FALSE) {
        //die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        Log::error('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    else{
        //echo $result;
        Log::error($result);
    }

    // Close connection
    /*curl_close($ch);
     echo $result/*."\n\n".json_encode($fields); */

}

}
?>
```

This is  my const.php

```
<?php

    define('TEAM','team');

    define('MESSAGE' , 'message');

?>
```

This is my firebase messanging code:

```
public class MessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "FCM Message";

public MessagingService() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification());
}

private void sendNotification(String body) {


    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);


    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Codegama");
    notificationBuilder.setContentText(body);
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationBuilder.setSound(defaultSoundUri);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =  (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());




}
}
```

and this is the error I keep getting in logcat android studio :

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage$Notification.getBody()' on a null object reference
    at hr.trazim.client.services.MessagingService.onMessageReceived(MessagingService.java:32)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzd(Unknown Source:60)
    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown Source:6)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

2020-01-07 12:08:11.092 1732-29214/? E/ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (101, /0)

I was reading a lot on stackoverflow subjects like this and I couldn't find proper fix/solution. I hope this fix gonna help other devs like me find suitable answers without lossing too much time as I did.

P.S. In case you need my token I haven't migrated it yet but it's working here is the code :

```
public class InstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    super.onTokenRefresh();
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.e("FCMToken", refreshedToken);
    saveDeviceToken(refreshedToken);
}

private void saveDeviceToken(String token) {
    UserDataSource.getDataInstance().putDeviceToken(token);
}

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this link also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37350268/send-fcm-messages-from-server-side-to-android-device

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40256179/7229971 refer this link,  I think in android you don't need to change.

Comment: Yesterday ive tryed all the solutions provided in this post, i couldnt find the fix in it unfortunatley. Ive sid that for your first link ,im checking second now.

Comment: you are getting error in android right? back-end working fine ?

Comment: Backend sending data, but android cant handle it. Saying null

Comment: try to log `remoteMessage.toString()` in log cat.

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage$Notification.getBody()' on a null object reference

Comment: write this line above  sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()); in android `Log.d("Push data", remoteMessage.getData().toString());`
check what you get in logcat

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage$Notification.getBody()' on a null object reference < his is what i get.

Comment: first comment out this line sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

Comment: E/Response: {"success":true,"request_id":85,"message":"Peatelj je uno pri!"}

Comment: Happy to see that ?

Comment: Yeah but still need to make it working. How can i parse this into notification ?

Comment: now try to this one Log.d("Push data", remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));

Comment: Push data: {"data":{"page_type":"","request_id":"85"},"success":true,"title":"Us","type":5}
D/FCM Message: From: 1005368332618
D/FCM Message: Notification Message Body: null

Comment: are you sending any data in message from php?

Comment: Yes its comming from other files there is 2 apps..This Log.d("Push data", remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));  ive tryed yesterday ive found it in other solution ive found on stackoverflow

Comment: previously is working right ?

Comment: Yes , when it was GCM now endpoint url is FCM.

Comment: Okay then just replace our php code function with https://stackoverflow.com/a/40256179/7229971. you don't need to change in android code.

Comment: Ive added only part of code         'notification' => array (
                "body" => $mess,
                "title" => "Title",
                "icon" => "myicon" Now i get all this in notification, i will play with it now and let you know shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use this :

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)

public void show_Notification(){

Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
String CHANNEL_ID="MYCHANNEL";
NotificationChannel notificationChannel=new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,"name",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),1,intent,0);
Notification notification=new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(),CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentText("Heading")
        .setContentTitle("subheading")
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .addAction(android.R.drawable.sym_action_chat,"Title",pendingIntent)
        .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.sym_action_chat)
        .build();

NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
notificationManager.notify(1,notification);


 }
```

Comment: can you explain how its relevant to question error?

Comment: check below answer's comments

Comment: Im trying to implement this solution is this for androidx ? What will happen if api is under jelly as ive put minimum target 19

Comment: can take help from this blog for full integration: https://android.jlelse.eu/android-push-notification-using-firebase-and-advanced-rest-client-3858daff2f50

Comment: Thank you, ive fixed it. Thanks bro <3

Answer (score 0):

You are getting wrong data. it should be like this. or try to print data first then get from array.

```
sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
Log.d("Push data", remoteMessage.getData().toString());
```

Comment: Ive tryed and now i got this :
FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-MessagingService
    Process: hr.trazim.client, PID: 29556
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid notification (no valid small icon): Notification(channel=null pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=content://settings/system/notification_sound defaults=0x0 flags=0x10 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)

Answer (score 0):

To send [Firebase push notification](https://trinitytuts.com/firebase-push-notification-android/) from php server you can use this code.

```
<?php

function sendMessage($data, $target, $serverKey){
    //FCM api URL
    $rsp = [];
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    //api_key available in Firebase Console -> Project Settings -> CLOUD MESSAGING -> Server key
    $server_key = $serverKey;
    $fields = array();
    $fields['data'] = $data;
    if(is_array($target)){
            $fields['registration_ids'] = $target;
        }else{
            $fields['to'] = $target;
    }
    //header with content_type api key
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type:application/json',
        'Authorization:key='.$server_key
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        //die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    //print_r($result);
    return $result;
}
```

And if you want to update your android code you can follow this post: [Firebase push notification](https://trinitytuts.com/firebase-push-notification-android/)